# AWS - IdentityPool not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am writing an app to implement offline sync functionality using `Amazon Web Services (AWS)` I am following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/TodoAWS/) out-dated tutorial and keeping getting an error when trying to run my code with my current identity pool id.

`ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

I have set permissions for Auth and Non-Auth users using this JSON

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "sdb:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also allowed unauthenticated access:[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial code, you will see the function below

```
    public SimpleDBStorage()
    {
        var credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(
                              Constants.CognitoIdentityPoolId,
                              RegionEndpoint.<REGION>);
        var config = new AmazonSimpleDBConfig();
        config.RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.<REGION>;
        client = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials, config);

        Items = new List<TodoItem>();
        SetupDomain();
    }
```

You must update these regions to the region you are using in AWS.